# Django + mod_wsgi + apache2: server hangs

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am deploying a django project on apache2 using mod_wsgi, but the problem is that the server dont serve pages and it hangs for 10 minute before giving an error:

```
End of script output before headers
```

This is my **`site-available/000-default.conf`**:

```sh
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/artfact/arTfact_webSite/
Alias /static /home/artfact/arTfact_webSite/static
        <Directory /home/artfact/arTfact_webSite/static>
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
         Require all granted
        </Directory>

      <Directory /home/artfact/arTfact_webSite>
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
         <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
         </Files>
      </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess artfact_site processes=5 threads=25  python-path=/home/artfact/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/:/home/artfact/arTfact_webSite

        WSGIProcessGroup artfact_site
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/artfact/arTfact_webSite/arTfact_webSite/wsgi.py
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for arTfact_webSite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = xxxx

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'website',
    'blog',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'arTfact_webSite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'arTfact_webSite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

**wsgi.py**

```py
"""
WSGI config for arTfact_webSite project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "arTfact_webSite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Project structure**

```sh
arTfact_webSite/
├── arTfact_webSite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── blog
├── static
├── media
└── website
    ├── admin.py
    ├── admin.pyc
    ├── forms.py
    ├── forms.pyc
    ├── general_analyser.py
    ├── general_analyser.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __init__.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── models.pyc
    ├── send_mail.py
    ├── send_mail.pyc
    ├── static
    │   └── website
    ├── templates
    │   └── website
    ├── tests.py
    ├── tests.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── views.py
    └── views.pyc
```

In the **arTfact_webSite/urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/*', include('website.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In the **website/urls.py**

```py
    urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `End of script output before headers` error means that your app crashes before sending any response. Try the following test. Stop apache, switch to /home/artfact/arTfact_webSite/arTfact_webSite and try to run `python manage.py runserver` command. It should start a development server, but chances are it will give you an error of some sort, indicating what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a ServerName or ServerAlias in your VirtualHost block:

```
ServerName www.example.com
```

I am assuming your Apache configs above are inside a VirtualHost block like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an **'a'** in your *wsgi.py* file between the lines

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "arTfact_webSite.settings") 
a
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

no sure if this is in your actual file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the command:

apachectl configtest

This should help you isolate what is broken in your apache configuration. See this link for more information:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apachectl.html

If it reports 'Syntax OK', then you know that it's a configuration **detail** problem rather than a configuration syntax problem.

Otherwise, posting your apache2 logs would be helpful.